# How to print a heap in sorted order without changing it?

Tags: heap

I want to print a heap in sorted order (from min to max), but do not change the heap.
I know I can do remove_min to a temp array and print until it is empty and insert back.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach would be to make a copy of the heap, and then remove_min from the copy. (This is basically the same as the second half of HeapSort.)

Emptying out the original heap, and then refilling it, will change the internal ordering of the heap elements. While this wouldn't cause any visible effects on the heap's external behavior (other than making future `remove_min`s slightly faster), it would still technically be "changing the heap".